# Why My ViewController UI Freezing / Hanging on iOS 11 only?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios11

My App's ChatViewController is hanging / freezing UI on iOS 11 or above Device only. But in IOS 10 or below it's working fine. I'm Using Socket.io Chat..

Following screenshots were taken from 2 different devices and ios version.

1. iPhone 5 - iOS 10.3.3
   [image: ChatViewController | iPhone 5 - iOS 10.3.3]

   - Backbutton Action - **Working**
   - inputBar - **Working**
   - Send Button Action - **Working**
   - Scroll through the Message - **YES**
     ** Responses - **Receiving**
2. iPhone 6 - iOS 11.1.2
   [image: =]

   - Backbutton Action - **Not Working**
   - inputBar - **Not Working**
   - Send Button Action - **Not Working**
   - Scroll through the Message - **YES**
     ** Responses - **Receiving**

Please help me to find out the exact issue.. by referring the above screenshots and the below codes.

```
-(void) createNavLeftButton
{
    UIImage *buttonImageNavNormal =[UIImage imageNamed:@"bnt_bck_normal.png"];
    UIImage *buttonImageNavHigh = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bnt_bck_pressed.png"];
    UIButton *cancelButton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cancelButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,buttonImageNavHigh.size.width,buttonImageNavHigh.size.height)];
    [cancelButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,buttonImageNavNormal.size.width,buttonImageNavNormal.size.height)];
    [cancelButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImageNavHigh forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [cancelButton setImage:buttonImageNavNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIBarButtonItem *containingcancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                               initWithCustomView:cancelButton];
    UIBarButtonItem *negativeSpacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                       initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace
                                       target:nil action:nil];
    negativeSpacer.width = -5; //it was -6 in iOS 6  you can set this as per your preference
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:negativeSpacer,containingcancelButton, nil] animated:NO];
}

-(void)backButtonPressed{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(void)setInputbar
{
    self.inputbar.placeholder = @"Type a message";
    self.inputbar.delegatee = self;
    self.inputbar.leftButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"share"];
    self.inputbar.rightButtonText = @"Send";
    self.inputbar.rightButtonTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:124/255.0 blue:1 alpha:1];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setInitialProperties];
    if (!socket || !socketWrapper) {
        socket = [ChatSIOClient sharedInstance];
        socketWrapper = [ChatSocketIOClient sharedInstance];
    }

    socketWrapper.chatDelegate = self;
        [self setInputbar];
    [self.navigationItem addLeftSpace];
    self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"JOB ID:%@",_bid];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"OnChatController"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 1];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    if(!self.inputbar)
    {
        self.inputbar = [[Inputbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 44,  self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];
        [self setInputbar];
        [self.view addSubview:self.inputbar];
    }


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                               object:nil];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}
```

Navigation Item UI IB

[image: Navigation Item UI IB]

Comment: Is your back button and user profile logo are in UINavigationBar? or they are just on the custom UIView? Try to debug UI in 3D option and you can see if any other views are overlapping.That's the most probable cause in your case.

Comment: @VishalSonawane it's inside navigation Item check the bottom of the edited question for the screen shot .. Btw input bar also not activating... though it's set up programatically.

Comment: I clearly see the actual bar buttons are outside of their superview's frame, therefore they are not really part of any responder-chain... I don't know anything about the "send" button, seemingly it looks okay, but the reason could be just the same.

Comment: I fixed Navigation Button.. But Still the Input bar is not working for iOS 11 only